# Using F# how do I access an element that doesn't have the same namespace as the document?

Tags: f#, linq-to-xml

This is my very first attempt at F#, I know I still need to read a lot and I will, but these challenges help me understand the next parts I will read better, so far I managed to solve some of the first challenges, so please be patient......

The xml document looks like this:

```
<BuildCollection xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <PostEvents xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels.Events">
        <a:EventBase i:type="a:ExternalProcess">
            <a:Description>Structuring assemblies</a:Description>
```

How do I access the elements that start with "a:......."?

In C# I would do it like this:

```
foreach (var postBuildEventElement in 
    document
        .Root.Element(ns + "PostEvents")
        .Elements()
        .Where(_ => _.Name.LocalName == "EventBase"))
```

So far in F# I have this:

```
module PostBuildInstructions

open System.Xml.Linq
open System.Linq

let xn s = XName.Get(s)

let PostBuildInstructions (xdoc: System.Xml.Linq.XDocument) =
    xdoc.Root.Elements(xn "PostEvents").Elements().Where(e => e.)

let ExecutePostBuildInstructions buildDescriptor =
    let "I need to enumerate the post build events here"
```

In the "main" code block I started with this: (I'm focusing on line 6 with this question)

```
open Log

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    TryLogArgs argv
    ReadPostBuildInstructions |> ExecutePostBuildInstructions
    log "Press enter to exit"
    System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Lambda expressions in F# are written as `fun x -> ...` Have you tried googling?

Comment: I'm not asking about lamdas. Yes I googled my question, but not lamdas since that was not the question.

Comment: In your F# code you have `.Where(e => e.)`. That is not how lambda expressions are written in F#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of the `xn` function is not equivalent to the use in the C# version.  Your `xn` function returns a name with no associated namespace.  However you're dealing with names within namespaces you you should be generating names as such.

Your C# version should ideally be like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels";
XNamespace a = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels.Events";
var query = doc.Root
    .Elements(ns + "PostEvents")
    .Elements(a + "EventBase");
```

The F# version shouldn't be that much different:

```
let ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels")
let a = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels.Events")
let query = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "PostEvents").Elements(a + "EventBase")
```

But you may want to keep them as function calls. Just make sure you associate with the correct namespaces for the functions.

```
let xn n = XName.Get(n)
let ns n = XName.Get(n, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels")
let a n = XName.Get(n, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BuildModels.Events")
let query = doc.Root.Elements(ns "PostEvents").Elements(a "EventBase")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wan't looking for an improvement on the C# code but you gave me a tip there too. Awesome.